# MySQL - what happends when update a column by rand() or by now()?

Tags: mysql

I have a table:

```
CREATE TABLE `test` (
 `t` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

and update it by:

```
update test set t = rand();
```

then the data in the table is:

```
+---------------------+
| t                   |
+---------------------+
| 0.24891147599454175 |
| 0.5710943421079725  |
| 0.10873731328988198 |
+---------------------+
```

as you see, every 't' is different

when update the table using:

```
update test set t = now(6);
```

and every 't' is the same:

```
+----------------------------+
| t                          |
+----------------------------+
| 2018-03-13 23:40:40.380817 |
| 2018-03-13 23:40:40.380817 |
| 2018-03-13 23:40:40.380817 |
+----------------------------+
```

what happends when update a column by rand() or by now()?

Answer (score 1):

`RAND()` is recalculated per row. While `NOW()` will allways be the same value anywhere in the same statement. That all has nothing to do with UPDATE. It works the same with SELECT. Try the follwing:

```
select rand()
from (select 1 union all select 1 union all select 1) x;

select now(6)
from (select 1 union all select 1 union all select 1) x;
```

You will see the same effect.

Demo: http://rextester.com/JGJWV3591

Answer (score 0):

The `now()` function returns the time when the statement begin to execute and is not recalled for every row while `RAND()` is recalled for every row. From the [MYSQL](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_now) documentation:

> NOW() returns a constant time that indicates the time at which the
>   statement began to execute. (Within a stored function or trigger,
>   NOW() returns the time at which the function or triggering statement
>   began to execute.) This differs from the behavior for SYSDATE(), which
>   returns the exact time at which it executes.

so you can use `SYSDATE()` instead of `NOW()`. This way every row will be different

```
update test set t = SYSDATE();
```

Answer (score 0):

The documentation for MySQL functions `rand()` and `now()` explain how those functions work, so I won't repeat much of that here. For reference:

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mathematical-functions.html#function_rand
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_now

When you run the first statement with `rand()`, you get random floating point numbers greater than or equal to 0 and less than 1. When you run the second statement:

```
update test set t = now(6);
```

The seconds value is represented with a precision of 6 decimal places, as specified. The overall value returned represents the time *at which the statement **began** to execute*. That's why all the values are identical.